# Is it safe to use a hdd with suspicious sectors?

Tags: hard-drive

So I have this 1TB 2.5 inch HGST hdd, that shows to have had only 630 hours of runtime in crystaldisk info. Crystal disk describes the hdd state as "warning" and it shows that the drive has 51 "suspicious sectors". My question is if this drive would be safe to use for non critical data as long as it does not develop any bad sectors or if it needs to be replaced imediatelly.

Comment: You might need Spinright

Comment: Spinright first is a good suggestion from other comment.  Even run chkdsk /f or /r and see what it says.. play with it.  I myself would... 1) partition around the bad sectors, leave a gap on each side. 2) not store anything that I can't recover or might make the system SUCK if it hits a bad sector (aka system, temp, etc).  Using a bad drive won't hurt your system but if you hit bad sectors while it is attempting to read, your system might slow to a crawl and suck badly.

Comment: Format the disk using the slow (not fast) method to renew the disk. All data will of course be lost.

Answer (score 0):

If CrystaldiskInfo considers pending sectors as "suspicious sectors" your drive is not safe after such a short time period of use.

Unfortunately your title question contradicts your statement about "non-critical data". If you don't mind about loosing data why are you asking the question then?